# CryptXML CryptXmlOpenToEncode returns E_INVALIDARG for namespace element

Tags: xml, signing

This CryptXML [sample code](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/security/cryptoapi/cryptxml) works when running:

**CryptXML.exe -n Contoso SIGN FileOut.xml FileIn.xml /samlpEnvelope #**

where FileIn.xml is defined as

```
<samlpEnvelope xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Data>
    Hello, World!
  </Data>
</samlpEnvelope>
```

However, running this with the colon ":" namespace added

**CryptXML.exe -n Contoso SIGN FileOut.xml FileIn.xml /samlp:Envelope #**

```
<samlp:Envelope xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Data>
    Hello, World!
  </Data>
</samlp:Envelope>
```

produces this error in [CryptXmlOpenToEncode()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd433830(v=vs.85).aspx):

***ERROR: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)***

Anyone know how-to get CryptXML to understand the colon in the element name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A colleague programmer suggested this and it works!

**CryptXML.exe -n Contoso SIGN FileOut.xml FileIn.xml /Envelope #**